# Tuple-Array with variable content types & length?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

Working on a little debug function for proper output of data, I came across a problem with Tuple-Arrays. Apparently I cannot declare Arrays of Tuples with flexible contained data types and sizes.

I am tying to support various types of Tuple-Arrays like
`[(String, Int, Int, String)]` and `[(Int, Int, Bool)]`, not just one.

This is my current attempt, but I am unable to declare the Tuple Array

(Also the second for loop's counter seems to be incorrect as well?)

```
func debugData(names: [String], data: [(*magic tupel*)] ) {
    var debugLine = ""
    for line in 0..<data.count {
        for i in 0..<(data[line].count) {
            debugLine += "\(names[i])=\(data[line].i) "
        }
        print(debugLine)
        debugLine = ""
    }
}
```

I am trying to bring together two arrays like this:
`["Name", "Age", "SexM"]` and `[("Alex", 5, true), ("Lisa", 7, false), ("Max", 9, true)]`. The desired output (for the first element) would be something like `"Name=Alex, Age=5, SexM=true"` which would be a combination of both arrays.

Of cause I could simply go for `Array<(String, Int, Bool)>` in the function's declaration, at least in the example above, but I want this function to work for all kinds of data - with various Array sizes and flexible data types...

I guess it's not even that complicated, I'm just really new to Swift.

Comment: Why don't you just use a dictionary? Or in this particular case, a `Person` struct.

Comment: I already have quite some data packed in Tuple-Arrays which I am now trying to output. Still I'll consider those for future code :)

Comment: I would quite strongly advise you refactor those into structs or objects (instances of classes). Tuples are intended for very short lived data, and are very limited in many ways

Comment: Would you also advise not to use code as suggested by _vadian_, using CustomStringConvertible-Arrays? Or should they be fine? :)

Comment: It wins the battle but not the war.

Comment: @Alexander *There's more than one way to skin a cat* 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tuple is inappropriate because you cannot declare a tuple in a generic manner.

A possible solution is to declare `data` as an array of `CustomStringConvertible` instead of a tuple.

The benefit is you can pass any type which supports String Interpolation and the number of items in the array is variable.

```
func debugData(names: [String], data: [[CustomStringConvertible]] ) {
    var debugLine = ""
    for line in data {
        for i in 0..<line.count {
            debugLine += "\(names[i])=\(line[i]) "
        }
        print(debugLine)
        debugLine = ""
    }
}

debugData(names: ["Name", "Age", "SexM"], data: [["Alex", 5, true], ["Lisa", 7, false], ["Max", 9, true]])
```